# Can I define intent filter to receive intents from other app components in main activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Can I define intent filter to receive intents from other app components in main activity ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I misread your question. I though you were asking about receiving intents from other apps and not from components inside your own app. Although the answer is pretty close to your question it does not fully shows the fully correct information.

-- Intents within app--

You can. You need to register your main activity to receive those broadcast events. Then you just need to send a broadcast intent from the component you want and it will be triggered in the main activity.

More info @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

-- Intents from Other Apps --

Yes (with conditions) as in: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

> To deliver a broadcast:
>   A broadcast is a message that any app can receive. The system delivers various broadcasts for system events, such as when the system boots up or the device starts charging. You can deliver a broadcast to other apps by passing an Intent to sendBroadcast(), sendOrderedBroadcast(), or sendStickyBroadcast().

So you just need to know the broadcast intent URI and it only works if it is not a local/private broadcast.

Here is a quote explaining how to declare in your manifest to receive implicit intents

> To advertise which implicit intents your app can receive, declare one
>   or more intent filters for each of your app components with an
>    element in your manifest file. Each intent filter
>   specifies the type of intents it accepts based on the intent's action,
>   data, and category. The system will deliver an implicit intent to your
>   app component only if the intent can pass through one of your intent
>   filters.

And a snippet for intent action SEND to be place in your AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a working example of catching active intents have a look at [the sourcecode of intent-intercept@github](https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept)

it's [manifest-file](https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) contains about 90 lines of `<intent-filter... />` entries where all kind of interceptable intents are listed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,you can use intent-filters to receive data from another app.